# How to include observations with 'NA' while doing a comparison in data.table?

Tags: r, data.table

For a dataset as below

```
data <- data.table(ID = c(NA,1,1,NA,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,NA),
                   ABC = c(NA,2,3,NA,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,NA),
                   Marks = c(100,100,100,150,100,150,100,100,100, 90, 80, 100))

    ID ABC Marks
 1: NA  NA   100
 2:  1   2   100
 3:  1   3   100
 4: NA  NA   150
 5:  1   1   100
 6:  2   1   150
 7:  2   1   100
 8:  2   1   100
 9:  3   1   100
10:  3   1    90
11:  3   1    80
12: NA  NA   100
```

For code

```
data[ID == ABC]
```

How can I compare columns ID and ABC such that the observations with NA is also included in output?

**OUTPUT**

```
   ID ABC Marks
1:  1   1   100
```

**EXPECTED OUTPUT**

```
   ID ABC Marks
1: NA  NA   100
2: NA  NA   100
3:  1   1   100
4: NA  NA   100
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this:

```
data[ID == ABC | (is.na(ID) & is.na(ABC))]
```

Comment: Yes, this would do but just wondering if there is argument like na.rm = TRUE for this and also why NA are ignored.